# Why can't we model periodic phenomena using a single autonomous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the system below. It is used to model the interaction between predator and prey.

$$x' = x-xy, y' = -y + xy$$

The solution curves are closed contours about the point $(1,1)$.
I determined this by using that along any solution curve $$\frac{d(xe^{-x}ye^{-y})}{dt} = 0$$ (The above might be useful???)

"Briefly explain why the behaviour of each population separately cannot be described by a single autonomous differential equation"

I do not know what to say. Is it because each population separately would be periodic in nature? we can prove that we can not model oscillatory behaviour with autonomous differential equations fairly easily. I feel like I am falling into a pit here though.

Comment: Probably it means an equation of the form $x'=f(x)$, since a second-order ODE can of course have periodic solutions. Here's a hint: What does the phase portrait of such a first-order ODE look like? Can solutions return to where they started from?

Comment: No, solutions can not intersect. If we take two points on a solution to such an equation $x' = f(x)$ such that $x(t) = x(t+T) $ and $T > 0$ ...*some algebra*... we obtain T = 0.

Comment: Is that the answer that is required?

Comment: From http://www.eve.ucdavis.edu/sschreiber/reprints/differential-equations.pdf (pp 7 - 9), I would think they are looking for something like: When there is only one state variable, the solutions are monotonic: either the solution remains constant for all time, increases, or constantly decreases. Nonlinear feedback between two state variables introduces two new asymptotic behaviors for solutions: periodicity and heteroclinic cycles.

Comment: I like the explanation through Rolle's theorem: if $x(t) = x(t+T)$, then there exists time $t^\ast$ at which $x'(t^\ast)=f(x(t^\ast))=0$. But this means that $x(t^\ast)$ itself is an equilibrium and we have two trajectories that pass through the same point of phase space. If $f(x)$ is well-behaving function, we get a contradiction.